# API access to BIM360 trial accounts

Tags: autodesk-bim360

According to published documentation, BIM360 trial accounts and accounts with less than 100 Users are not allowed to enable API access. In that case, when a user adds a ‘BIM360 app’ from store to his/her account, how does the added 3rd party app obtain access token when user directly logs into that app (after adding to BIM360).

Thanks

Comment: According to Augusto's notes in BIM360 Hackathon (a year ago), this has to be a manual process to be performed by BIM360 account admin.

Does it mean there is no automated way to transfer Client ID to 3rd party app?

Answer (score 0):

The [Data Management API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/overview/) provides access to all Autodesk hubs, including BIM 360 Docs hubs (i.e. files). The [BIM 360 API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/) provides access to management of the account (e.g. create projects, add users, etc.).

Being an enterprise application, different users will have different levels of access, so only the **Admin** (1+ users) of the account can authorize an app to access its data, this is the [provisioning step](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/get-access-to-account/). This [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-docs-provisioning-forge-apps) suggests how apps should request their users to perform the steps. The provisioning process it's manual due security (i.e. the admin must explicitly integrate the account with the app)

By default, any new BIM 360 account is not API-enabled, so you need to request following [these steps](https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/bim-360-activating-api-access-to-docs/).

After provisioning, any user from that BIM 360 account that sign into your app will have permission to see the files he/she is allowed to. Here the 3-legged access token has the same level of permission as the user who authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Augusto! So, that means I won't be able to satisfy the BIM360 Store requirement that app should be immediately available for user. I will bring this up with AppStore team.

Another thing: Suppose admin grants the permission manually. Is there a way to 'transfer' Client ID and Client Secret to my app? Or is that something user has to 'copy and paste' manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Your app should be available immediately after the user provision the app, the AppStore requirement is around manual process that cannot be performed by the user.

Comment: About the Client ID process, please see the link describing a suggestion on how to handle it: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-docs-provisioning-forge-apps Most apps on the AppStore uses this approach